# The privileges page uses problematic styling

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, accessibility, privileges-page

[Prompt.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/congratulations-your-site-design-is-now-live/17762?noredirect=1#comment63407_17762)

1. The things I *can* do are faded to the point of unreadability, while the things I *cannot* do are more legible.
2. The hover effect is used to gain readability of faded items, but many devices have no concept of hovering (like phones and tablets, and browsers that use keystrokes for link navigation).

[image: Meta.SE]

[image: Judaism.SE]

Comment: In every other UI case I've seen, being [grayed out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayed_out) means something is *unavailable*.  Agree with this suggestion!

Comment: @A_S00 I suspect that this design is intended to goad users into a senseless pursuit of rep ;-)